# replacing white spaces in wxString, c++

Tags: c++, removing-whitespace, wxstring

I would like to replace every substring containing any number of white spaces in wxString to a single character or string of characters - for example ".*"  (in c++).

Alternatively, perhaps there is an easy way to convert each substring to a single whitespace. I could then use the wxString::Replace method in the second step to change the single whitespace into something else:
wxStringInstance.Replace(wxT(" "), wxT(".*"));

So, for example, if my wxString contains "Winter\s\s\s\s\s     is  coming", I would like to change it to
"Winter.*is.*coming", not to "Winter.*.*.*.*.*is.*.*.*coming".  Could anyone help me please?...  I would really appreciate it, thank you :)

Comment: Didn't you ask that recently? Why not be patient for answers?

Comment: This is the only question in my profile.

Comment: You apparently deleted the recent one and reposted it I've seen it.

Comment: thank you for your helpful insight :)

Comment: If you want to improve your question, you can always edit it to get better attention. Start out with providing a [MCVE] for example.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, build a little state machine, with two states, "on whitespace" or "on text". Then pass over the input (you might want to start in either state depending on how you handle leading whitespace). When you transition from "on text" to "on whitespace", you emit a space, when you are "on text" you emit the text, when you transition from "on whitespace" to "on whitespace" you emit nothing.